# What is ghostscript, why it is used?

Tags: ghostscript

I want to know about the ghostscript? I have seen that it is required for few softwares like cute pdf etc. What it does actually? Why it is used?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Apparently if you can google it, and a wiki article is sufficient to answer a non-problem question, it is not a question and will be closed by mods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Ghostscript is a package of software that provides:
>
> An interpreter for the PostScript (TM) language, with the ability to
>   convert PostScript language files to many raster formats, view them on
>   displays, and print them on printers that don't have PostScript
>   language capability built in;  An interpreter for Portable Document
>   Format (PDF) files, with the same abilities;  The ability to convert
>   PostScript language files to PDF (with some limitations) and vice
>   versa; and  A set of C procedures (the Ghostscript library) that
>   implement the graphics and filtering (data compression / decompression
>   / conversion) capabilities that appear as primitive operations in the
>   PostScript language and in PDF.

Taken from [Ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com/Ghostscript.html)

Comment: This should be directly on the homepage. How did you navigate to this page? I find it difficult to understand what Ghost script is from the current homepage.